# Move one store from multiple store magento to another server with multiple store

Tags: magento

I am having to move a store from a multiple store setup in magento dev server to a multiple store setup production server. What will be the best way to do this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

You can take a look at the link above for reference. You have to manually add the store and configure it via the admin panel. And ince you are only moving the files from dev to production, I assumed that they only have the same files. So you only have to make some redirects with the index.php file.